# Running sbt returns error : '-java-home requires <path> argument'

Tags: java, ubuntu, sbt

Java appears to be installed correctly :

```
which java
/usr/bin/java
java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Attempting to run sbt causes error  :

```
sbt run
-java-home requires <path> argument
```

Do I need to pass `<path>` as part of running sbt ?

I'm attempting to run sbt on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: how did you install sbt?  how are you running sbt (in the same directory where you have a build.sbt file)?

Comment: @alihaider outside of the project I run sbt from , sbt starts correctly. To fix I deleted and re-created the project. I don't know what caused the issue but it's no longer occuring

Answer (score 0):

I found my .sbtopts had a line w/ an invalid java home was somehow placed in it. removing the line fixed this for me.

Comment: Is it possible to set Java home path in `.sbtopts`?